# Groovy POST large content using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have the below code for doing a POST request to a REST API end point to update SAP application data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def call(total_record, url, bearer_token, scriptId, payload)  {

    Integer tot = total_record as Integer // Convert string to Integer
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    if (tot == 1) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("${url}");
        stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode("${scriptId}", "UTF-8"))
        URL put_url = new URL(stringBuilder.toString());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) put_url.openConnection()
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        println("Executing PUT")
    }
    else if (tot == 0) {
        URL post_url = new URL("${url}");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) post_url.openConnection()
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        println("Executing POST")
    }
    else {
        println("Total records can not be calculated")
    }
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", bearer_token);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
    connection.setDoOutput(true)
    OutputStream pos = connection.getOutputStream()
    pos.write(payload.getBytes())
    pos.flush();
    pos.close();
    println(connection.responseCode)
    def msg = null
    if(connection.responseCode == 200){
        msg = "Executing Deployment"
    }
    else{
        msg = "Error is Connection\n"
        msg += connection.responseCode
    }
    connection.disconnect()
    return msg
}
```

Reading the script/file content as input

```
File f = new File("out.py")
def content = f.readLines().toString()
```

Example Payload:

```
String payload = """{
                            "Definition": {
                            "name": "filename",
                            "modifiedBy": "user_name",
                            "active": true,
                            "systemId": "filename_sid",
                            "script": "${content}"

                            }
                        }"""
```

### Basically , I want to upload some python script content (python code) to API end point url.

#### The above code is working good when I simply post any random text which is not code.

#### But it gives 400 Bad Request when it reads the file content as code.Example error below:

my script file contains:

```
import clr
import sys
import System

# Testing Changes Priyabrata
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
clr.AddReference('System.Xml')
from System import DateTime, Random
Offeringid = ""
tableInfo = SqlHelper.GetTable("COMPOSIOTION")
```

Below is error response:

```
{"error":{"code":"110000","message":"One or more fields in the API request contains invalid data. See the log for more information","target":"/api/script/v1/globalscripts/37","details":[{"code":"110000","message":"ScriptDefinition.Script: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: S. Path 'ScriptDefinition.Script', line 13, position 18."}],"internalMessage":"Model validation failed"}}
```

However when i try to code in Python, script content also posted to endpoint using python requests module.

But this gives error i.e. 400 Bad Request in groovy.
I have a requirement to make the pipeline in groovy as per organization standard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTdEt.png)
Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your POST code is fine.

problem not in content size , but in a way you are building json payload.

you have doublequotes in `content`

so, using string interpolation  for json building like this:

```js
def content = 'println "world"'
def payload = """{ "script":"${content}" }"""
```

will give you incorrect json:

```js
{ "content": "println "world"" }
```

better to use `groovy.json.JsonBuilder` or `groovy.json.JsonOutput`

```js
def content = 'println "world"'
def payload = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([
    'active': true,
    'script': content 
]).toPrettyString()
```

this will result well-formatted json with all required escaped doublequotes and other special characters

```
{
    "active": true,
    "script": "println \"world\""
}
```

Comment: This is Great!!! You are awesome. Absolutely perfect solution. I just formatted the Json out to:  `code`def get_gs_payload = new JsonBuilder (ScriptDefinition:[
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "filename",
            "ModifiedBy": "username",
            "Active": true,
            "Script": content,
            "IsModule": true,
            "SystemId": "filename_sid"
    ]).toPrettyString()